# Number of subarrays with same 'degree' as the array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

So this problem was asked in a quiz and the problem goes like:

You are given an array 'a' with elements ranging from 1-10<sup>6</sup>  and the size of array could be maximum 10<sup>5</sup> Now we are asked to find the number of subarrays with the same 'degree' as the original array. Degree of an array is defined as the frequency of maximum occurring element in the array. Multiple elements could have the same frequency.

I was stuck in this problem for like an hour but couldn't think of any solution. How do I solve it?

#### Sample Input:

```
first-input
1,2,2,3,1
first-output 2
second-input
1,1,2,1,2,2
second-output 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The element that occurs most frequently is called the *mode*; this problem defines *degree* as the frequency count.  Your tasks are:

Identify all of the mode values.
For each mode value, find the index range of that value.  For instance, in the array

```
[1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

You have three modes (1 2 5) with a degree of 3.  The index ranges are

```
1 - 0:3
2 - 2:8
5 - 10:12
```

You need to count all index ranges (subarrays) that include at least one of those three ranges.

I've tailored this example to have both basic cases: modes that overlap, and those that do not.  Note that containment is a moot point: if you have an array where one mode's range contains another:

[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]

You can ignore the outer one altogether: any subarray that contains `0` will also contain `1`.

ANALYSIS

A subarray is defined by two numbers, the starting and ending indices.  Since we must have 0 <= start <= end <= len(array), this is the "handshake" problem between array bounds.  We have N(N+1)/2 possible subarrays.

For 10**5 elements, you could just brute-force the problem from here: for each pair of indices, check to see whether that range contains any of the mode ranges.  However, you can easily cut that down with interval recognition.

ALGORITHM

Step through the mode ranges, left to right.  First, count all subranges that include the first mode range [0:3].  There is only 1 possible starts [0] and 10 possible ends [3:12]; that's 10 subarrays.

Now move to the second mode range, [2:8].  You need to count subarrays that include this, but *exclude* those you've already counted.  Since there's an overlap, you need a starting point later than 0, *or* an ending point before 3.  This second clause is not possible with the given range.

Thus, you consider start [1:2], end [8:12].  That's 2 * 5 more subarrays.

For the third range [10:12 (no overlap), you need a starting point that does not include any other subrange.  This means that any starting point [3:10] will do.   Since there's only one possible endpoint, you have 8*1, or 8 more subarrays.

Can you turn this into something formal?

Answer (score 0):

Taking reference from leet code 
https://leetcode.com/problems/degree-of-an-array/solution/
solve

```
    class Solution {
        public int findShortestSubArray(int[] nums) {
            Map<Integer, Integer> left = new HashMap(),
                right = new HashMap(), count = new HashMap();

            for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
                int x = nums[i];
                if (left.get(x) == null) left.put(x, i);
                right.put(x, i);
                count.put(x, count.getOrDefault(x, 0) + 1);
            }

            int ans = nums.length;
            int degree = Collections.max(count.values());
            for (int x: count.keySet()) {
                if (count.get(x) == degree) {
                    ans = Math.min(ans, right.get(x) - left.get(x) + 1);
                }
            }
            return ans;
        }

}
```